# How do I resolve a promise in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to make a simple weather application based on Node.js, like [this one](https://github.com/evanshortiss/yr.no-forecast). My problem is that every mechanism I see is based on promises, and I don't understand the concept.

So, the code I see everywhere is like:

```
yrno.getWeather(LOCATION).then((weather) => {
    weather.getFiveDaySummary().then((data) => console.log('five day summary', data)); 
    weather.getForecastForTime(new Date()).then((data) => console.log('current weather', data));
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log('an error occurred!', e);
    });
```

However, I was unable to find a way to resolve these promises and save the five day summary to a variable for later use.

How do I proceed?

Thanks,
Robin

Comment: You should look up closures. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: Does `data` at last `.then()` function contain the data that you are trying to store?

Comment: You don't save the summary, you save the promise. When you want to use it, use the `then` method to wait for it and get passed the value as an argument.

Comment: I guess you start with [understanding the concept](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aren't promises just callbacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks)

Comment: @guest271314 yes it does.

Comment: @MeirionHughes How does linked Question resolve present Question?

Comment: @guest271314 The answer in the linked question answers "How do I resolve a promise in Node.js?" and "How to save the variable returned from a Promise"...

Comment: @MeirionHughes Where are two or more distinct `Promise` values stored in a  single variable at linked Question? The present Question could be a duplicate of an existing Question, though not as to currently linked Question; that is, without one of the answers being adjusted to account for expectation of two or more `Promise` values being available at single `.then()`.

Comment: @MeirionHughes Though since OP apparently is only interested in storing `Promise` value of `weather.getFiveDaySummary()` call, they could define a variable which is set to `Promise` value of `weather.getFiveDaySummary()` returned from `.then()`, omitting returning `weather.getForecastForTime(new Date())`

Comment: fair enough; I'll retract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the `Promise` returned from `yrno.getWeather(LOCATION)` call to a variable.

Use `Promise.all()` to return results from both `weather.getFiveDaySummary()` and `weather.getForecastForTime(new Date())` calls.

Chain `.then()` to the result of call to get the data at initial and subsequent `.then()` chained to variable identifier which returned initial `Promise` values.

```
let weatherData = yrno.getWeather(LOCATION).then(weather => {
  // note `return`, alternatively omit `return` and `{`, `}` at arrow function
  // .then(weather => Promise.all(/* parameters */))
  return Promise.all([weather.getFiveDaySummary()
                    , weather.getForecastForTime(new Date())]);
});

weatherData
// `results` is array of `Promise` values returned from `.then()`
// chained to `yrno.getWeather(LOCATION).then((weather)`
.then(results => {
  let [fiveDaySummary, forecastForTime] = results; 
  console.log('five day summary:', fiveDaySummary
             , 'current weather:', forecastForTime); 
  // note `return` statement, here
  return results
})
.catch(e => {
  // `throw` `e` here if requirement is to chain rejected `Promise`
  // else, error is handled here
  console.log('an error occurred!', e);
});

// weatherData
// .then(results => { // do stuff with `results` from first `weatherData` call })
// .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: If you indent your code properly, it would not look so much like you have code after a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using promises directly is to use await/async.

```
// weather.js  
const yrno = require('yr.no-forecast')({
  version: '1.9', // this is the default if not provided,
  request: {
    // make calls to locationforecast timeout after 15 seconds
    timeout: 15000
  }
});

const LOCATION = {
  // This is Dublin, Ireland
  lat: 53.3478,
  lon: 6.2597
};

async function getWeather() {

  let weather = await yrno.getWeather(LOCATION);
  let fiveDaySummary = await weather.getFiveDaySummary();
  let forecastForTime = await weather.getForecastForTime(new Date());

  return {
    fiveDaySummary: fiveDaySummary,
    forecastForTime: forecastForTime,
  }
}

async function main() {
  let report;

  try {
    report = await getWeather();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('an error occurred!', e);
  }

  // do something else... 
  if (report != undefined) {
    console.log(report); // fiveDaySummary and forecastForTime
  }
}

main(); // run it
```

you can run this (node.js 7) with:

`node --harmony-async-await weather`

You can use await/async on older targets by using Babel or Typescript to transpile it down for you.

Bonus (based off your comments) - I wouldn't do it this way, but just to show you it can be done:

```
const http = require('http');

const port = 8080;

http.createServer(
  async function (req, res) {
    let report = await getWeather(); // see above
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.write("" + JSON.stringify(report.fiveDaySummary));
    res.end('Hello World\n');
  })
  .listen(port);
```

[image]

again with `node --harmony-async-await weather` or transpile it.

Comment: You don't even need the `--harmony` since 7.6.

Comment: Wow,. I need to try this, as it's awesome.

It's not my preferred answer and I haven't tested it yet, but I am looking forward to trying it! Thank you very much!